# How to properly define stream operators for templates in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

I've defined transforming functions `fromString` and `toString` to work with any type.
They uses stream operators (<<) (>>).
Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

template <class Num1>
struct Foo
{
    Num1 X, Y;
};

template <class T>
string toString( T (a))//////
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    return(ss.str());
}

template <class T>
T fromString(const string &str)
{
    stringstream ss(str);
    T result;
    ss>>result;
    return(result);
}

template <class T>
void proc_FromString(const string &str, T (&a))
{
    a = fromString<T>(str);
};

template <class Num>
istream &operator>>(istream &input,Foo<Num> &c)
{
    input>>c.X>>c.Y;
    return input;
};


template <class Num>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Foo<Num> (&c))
{
    output<<"Foo("<<c.X<<","<<c.Y<<")";
    return output;
};

int main(int argNum, char *args[])
{
    Foo<int> fa;
    proc_FromString("1 2",fa);
    int a;
    cout<<toString(a)<<endl;
    cout<<toString(fa)<<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

It works. But it's not very optimal:

```
template <class T>
string toString( T (a))//////
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    return(ss.str());
}
```

I'm copying arguments in function here instead of giving arguments via reference.

Well. I suggested this changes will make it better (redefined in code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

template <class Num1>
struct Foo
{
    Num1 X, Y;
};

template <class T>
string toString(const T (&a))////// Redefining there!!!!
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    return(ss.str());
}

template <class T>
T fromString(const string &str)
{
    stringstream ss(str);
    T result;
    ss>>result;
    return(result);
}

template <class T>
void proc_FromString(const string &str, T (&a))
{
    a = fromString<T>(str);
};

template <class Num>
istream &operator>>(istream &input,Foo<Num> &c)
{
    input>>c.X>>c.Y;
    return input;
};


template <class Num>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Foo<Num> (&c))
{
    output<<"Foo("<<c.X<<","<<c.Y<<")";
    return output;
};

int main(int argNum, char *args[])
{
    Foo<int> fa;
    proc_FromString("1 2",fa);
    int a;
    cout<<toString(a)<<endl; //This works!
    cout<<toString(fa)<<endl; // This not works!
    return(0);
}
```

And get compilation error on my template structure. And error occurs only on my Foo structure.

```
stud\1mTRPO\labs\v3\experiment\main.cpp||In instantiation of 'std::string toString(const T&) [with T = Foo<int>; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]':|
stud\1mTRPO\labs\v3\experiment\main.cpp|59|required from here|
stud\1mTRPO\labs\v3\experiment\main.cpp|19|error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|600|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Foo<int>]'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 2 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|
```

Please, help me to properly fix that.

I think the reason is in unproperly defined `<<` operator.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your operator `<<` takes `c` as non-const reference, so it cannot bind to the `const T&` used in `toString()`. Change the operator like this:

```
template <class Num>
ostream &operator<< (ostream &output, const Foo<Num> &c)
{
    output<<"Foo("<<c.X<<","<<c.Y<<")";
    return output;
};
```